# Criterion of very ampleness of $L^{\otimes 2}$ where $L$ is ample line bundle on abelian variety.

Tags: abelian-varieties, line-bundles

Let $A$ be abelian variety, and $L$ be an ample line bundle on $A$.

Then by Lefschetz's theorem $L^{\otimes 3}$ is very ample.

I want to know  good criterion if $L^{\otimes 2}$ is very ample.